# How to configure FTP in Cisco Meraki?

Tags: cisco, firewall, tftp

Has anyone configured FTP rules in the Meraki MX family of network devices?

Locally, inside the LAN, I can login to the FTP server (IIS Windows 2012 server) without problems; but, I cannot login from outside (via WAN).

The FTP Server uses Passive mode.

Later I'm going to attached links from Meraki and YouTube websites that I have already tried.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: I am also having the same issue, URL works from inside but not from outside

Comment: Hi Ovidio Vazquez, what have u done. would be great if you could help on this case.

Answer (score 4):

[Active and Passive FTP Overview and Configuration](https://documentation.meraki.com/MX-Z/NAT_and_Port_Forwarding/Active_and_Passive_FTP_Overview_and_Configuration)

Under Security Appliance > Firewall, configure a 1:1 NAT with the allowed inbound connections.

> Two firewall rules are necessary for passive FTP to function properly:
>   - The firewall must allow connections on port 21.
>   - The firewall must allow connections to the ephemeral ports used by the FTP application.

Comment: You should not post link-only questions. Links go bad over time. You should edit your question to quote the relevant portions from the link, and use the link as the reference.

Answer (score 0):

Allow port forward on TCP 21 to your server

Same for TCP 50000 - 50100 following advice of https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Network_Configuration#Active_mode

Worked for me on Meraki MX64w